# Loop over Tokens in RapidMiner's Text Processing Plugin

Tags: text-mining, natural-language, rapidminer

is there any possibility to iterate over the tokens of a text document within RapidMiner? My first try was to window the document after tokenisation. But this seems very complicated.

I'm doing this to simulate the creation of a language model like Katz Backoff and so on. Maybe there is a better way to produce language models but in the moment i can only think of iterating the tokens and calculate the values and store them into an example set.

Thank you

Andreas

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do?

The "Process documents from ..." operators can calculate TF/IDF, Term Frequency, Term Occurences and binary term occurences for you if you select the appropriate option.

The result of "Process documents from ..." is a structure where each token (term) an attribute that has a value for each document. You can use the Loop Attributes operator to calculate something for each attribute.

For example, I used Loop Attributes to sum up the TF/IDF of each attribute (not that it makes sense but it illustrates what you can do).

I added the Loop Attributes after the Process Documents step and set the following options:

Attribute filter type: value_type
Value type: real (as the TF/IDF vectors are real numbers)

Loop Attributes creates a macro that can be used to reference the attribute currently in the loop.

Inside Loop Attributes I added a Generate Aggregations operator with the following options:

Attribute name: sumatt_%{loop_attribute}
Attribute filter type: single
Attribute: %{loop_attribute}

The result is a sum attribute for each attribute (token).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. With this procedure i can't access the order of the terms in a document. The document term matrix is just a bag of words approach. What i'm doing is the extraction of all n-gram statistics up to tri-grams. I could try to process the documents 3 times for all the n-gram types. But i thougt there might be a better way to produce n-gram language models.